# Angular login button is disabled when the browser stores the credentials

Tags: html, angular, button, angular-material

I have a problem in my angular application. I am using angular material. When the browser stores my login credentials, I have the login form filled in but the button is disabled.
[image with button disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSXTT.png)
Below is my html code:

**login.component.html**

```
<form class="z-depth center" flex="50" style="text-align: left;" *ngIf="currentUser == null || (currentUser != null && currentUser.LockoutEnabled===true)" class="example-form" [formGroup]="signin" (ngSubmit)="login(signin)" flex="50">
            <table style='margin: auto auto auto auto; width: 50%;'>
                <tr>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field class="dp" style="height: 55px; padding-top: 5px;">
                                <input #inputEmail matInput class="dp" placeholder="Username" ngDefaultControl formControlName="email" autofocus>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inputIcon" style="width: 5%;">
                            <i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 40px;">
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field class="dp" style="height: 55px; padding-top: 5px;">
                                <input #inputPassword matInput class="dp" placeholder="Password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" ngDefaultControl formControlName="password" required>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <i *ngIf="hide" class="fas fa-eye-slash" style="font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;" (click)="hide = !hide"></i>
                            <i *ngIf="!hide" class="fas fa-eye" style="font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;" (click)="hide = !hide"></i>
                        </td>
                        <td class="inputIcon" style="width: 5%;">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <label id='text' style="text-align: right; display: block; font-size: 13px; margin-top:10px;" (click)="openDialog()">{{ForgotPassword | translate}}</label>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div>
                        <button ejs-button [disabled]="!(signin.valid)" style='width: 250px; margin-top: 30px; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 10px; height: 40px; text-transform: lowercase; text-transform: capitalize;' [ngClass]="{'disabled' : !signin.valid, 'enabled': signin.valid}">{{LoginLabel | translate}}</button>
                    </div>                        
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

How can I fix so that the button is enabled if form is completed with the credentials stored by the browser?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `cdkAutofill` directive (and `AutofillMonitor` service if you need it). It's part of the CDK - docs [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/text-field/overview#monitoring-the-autofill-state-of-an-input). So on both your fields you could try doing something like this:

```
(cdkAutofill)="signin.updateValueAndValidity()"
```

Which should update the validity state of your form and, in turn, possible enable the button.